# Reading Mail Merge Field Using Aspose

Tags: mailmerge, aspose

While reading mail merge field using Aspose Words I got incorrect result for fields like {MAILMERGE Country Name}, it is only reading it as Country and not as Country Name.

An older version of Aspose was actually reading the field as Country Name. The newer version reads that field as Country Name only when we do {MAILMERGE "Country Name" }.

Can anyone point out on standard practice on creating the mail merge field and if we have any library in Aspose which would read the tag correctly even without quotation marks.

Comment: Which version of Aspose.Words are you using? I gave it a try with v13.3 using the code given on [this docs page](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Execute+Simple+Mail+Merge). It worked fine, even when I put space in merge field.

Comment: I was using wordDocument.MailMerge.GetFieldNames() in version 11.8

Comment: Word itself will typically replace space characters in merge field names by underscores, so it is not usually necessary to use quotation marks. With "mapped fields", where you have e.g. { MAILMERGE "Courtesy Title" \m }, when you insert such a field in Word (I'm looking at 2010) Word will insert the Quotation marks. But { MAILMERGE Courtesy Title \m } and even { MAILMERGE Courtesy \m } work just as well. Also probably not relevant to you, but in the field mapping/matching dialog, if you map to a name that contained spaces, you see the spaces not the underscores in the dialog (and in VBA).